# Streaming video without an internet connection

Tags: wifi, streaming

I have a customer that wants to stream his Iphone 5 and iPad video and audio files over his wireless network.  this network is not connected to the internet 80% of the time making using an Apple TV nearly impossible.  Is there any other hardware, such as a WiFi Blu-ray player that would be capable of doing this procedure for him?

The reason this network is not connected to the internet most of the time is that it is in his private jet that only gets internet above 10k feet and only within the continental US

Comment: Do you want to stream video *from* the iOS devices or *to* them?

Answer (score 2):

You dont need the internet connection to stream, you just need a wifi network (a router; example: stream from the iphone to the apple tv via an airport express creating a network). If you neglect DRM-protected stuff that is, which needs access to the internet.

Apparently you just have to activate the apple tv beforehand though, which requires an internet connection.

Another option would be a Chromecast.

Comment: Chromecast is not an option as it requires Internet Cconnection in order to work. I will look into the Apple TV product but I know Chromecast is not good.